# Access VBA won't let me define a recordset

Tags: ms-access, authentication, vba, recordset

So here's my pretty simple code for a login system..

Every time I try to run it I get; "Compile Error: User-Defined Type Not Defined"
This is something I've never seen before as access highlights the line "Dim rsLogin As Recordset"

Anyways heres the rest of the code:

```
Private Sub Label15_Click()

Dim StaffID, Password As String
Dim Match As Integer
Dim rsLogin As Recordset

If IsNull(Me.Password) And IsNull(Me.StaffID) Then
    MsgBox ("Please enter login information")

End If
If IsNull(Me.StaffID) Then                                                             
MsgBox ("Please enter a Staff ID.")

End If
If IsNull(Me.Password) Then
MsgBox ("Please enter a Password.")

End If

Match = 1
StaffID = Me.StaffID                                                             
Password = Me.Password

Set rsLogin = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblStaff", dbOpenDynaset)                  
rsLogin.MoveFirst

Do Until rsLogin.EOF = True                                                         
    If rsLogin!StaffID = StaffID And rsLogin!Password = Password Then   
        gblUser = rsLogin!StaffID                                           
        Match = 2                                                                   
        Exit Do
    Else
        rsLogin.MoveNext                                                            
    End If
Loop

If Match = 1 Then
MsgBox ("Incorrect StaffID and/or Password.")                             
ElseIf Match = 2 Then                                                                   
DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenForm ("frmMain")

End If


End Sub
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Where are you defining `Recordset`?

Comment: Access version? ADO or DAO?

Comment: The result is assigned by CurrentDb so it expects a DAO recordset.

Comment: `Project - References`, is there anything `MISSING`?

Answer (score 0):

Try prefix it with DAO:

```
dim rsLogin as DAO.Recordset
```

Also check if no references are missing. Missing references (referenced but not present/installed) will also cause compiler errors on the most basic built-in functions.

Comment: Just edited the code, there's no change.. How strange

Comment: Debug>compile gives the same error? Already tried compact/repair?